# Java console not showing when running applications

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

There is an option on Java Control Panel to display console when a Java application is started. I don't know why, but this console is not showing when I run JavaFX applications (Java 7 update 51).

Comment: What Java application do you try to open? Open http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/index.html : does the console open for this?

Comment: It is my own JavaFX application.